Where to Place Scripts that Are Executed on Network Change in 24.04 Server
Where is the place to put scripts that need to be executed on changes to the network for Ubuntu 24.04 server?  For example, when DHCP is renewed or connected, I need to reconfigure routing for a specific interface.

This helped (Using Ubuntu 24.04 out of the box):
sudo systemctl start networkd-dispatcher

references:

https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/configuring-networks#networkd-dispatcher-for-hook-scripts
man networkd-dispatcher
man networkctl

Put scripts in /etc/networkd-dispatcher/xxxxx.d where xxxxx is the state (carrier, degraded, dormant, no-carrier, off, routable)
According to errors in log - scripts need to have permissions 755
Following test script works for me (place it in any of the state directories and tail the syslog):
#!/bin/sh -e

logger "$0 1 $IFACE 2 $STATE 3 $ESSID 4 $ADDR 5 $IP_ADDRS 6 $IP6_ADDRS 7 $AdministrativeState 8 $OperationalState"

